# Getting errors when include <WinSock2> on Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, winsock2, allegro5

I'm trying to compile my project where I've just added the use of 'WinSock2.h'.I'm getting these errors :

```
    c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\um\wingdi.h(2898): error C2208: '_POINTL' : no members defined using this type
    c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\um\winuser.h(14564): error C2208: 'unsigned int'  : no members defined using this type
    more
```

I have searched solutions to my issue, I've added _WINSOCKAPI_ on preprocesseur rules and only the two errors up there are remaining. I have also tried adding WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN and still the same.

My project uses ALLEGRO library and "windows.h" file.

Have you a explanation of my problem ?

Comment: Could you please tell us, what is the order of your header files? I suggest you could try to put winsock2.h first.The problem is that windows.h includes the older winsock.h (unless you do something to stop it) which collides with the newer winsock2.h. But if you include winsock2.h before windows.h, then windows.h spots you've already got sockets support and doesn't include winsock.h.

Comment: I got rid of winsock2.h include in order only to use winsock.h throught windows.h.
In this configuration I only include windows.h.
Still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The compilator errors point to files winuser, wingdi, propild, oaidl.
These files has been added from the use of network library, on windows.h I guess.
The offending lines deal of following field definitions : unit, date, position.
All these name was already used on preprocessor definition on my project, leading to a conflict of definition.